# Modify model on change of input value inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have a table where I list some products with some inputs, basically what I want is to change an input value when another changes, here's the `<tr>`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="bought_product in vm.bought_products track by bought_product.id">
    <td>
        {{ bought_product.name }}
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control"
               min="1" max="1000" placeholder="#"
               ng-model="bought_product.quantity">
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            <!-- This is the input where I'll insert a price -->
            <input type="number" class="form-control no-spin"
                   min="1" max="1000" placeholder="#" ng-change="vm.calculateVatPrice(bought_product.price)"
                   ng-model="bought_product.price">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            <!-- This input will automatically be filled -->
            <input type="number" class="form-control no-spin"
                   min="1" max="1000" placeholder="#"
                   ng-model="bought_product.vat_price">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What do you mean "when another changes"?

Comment: @ShaohaoLin When input 1 values change then calculate the value at input 2

Comment: All you need to do is change `$scope.bought_product.vat_price` in `$scope.vm.calculateVatPrice(bought_product.price)`

Comment: @JohannesJander Don't know if you didn't notice, it is inside a `ng-repeat`, so `bought_product.vat_price` is not a simple value to change from the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to replace your

```
ng-change="vm.calculateVatPrice(bought_product.price)"
```

by

```
ng-change="vm.calculateVatPrice(bought_product)"
```

and inside your vm.calculateVatPrice function you will have to calculate and set the vat_price like this

```
calculateVatPrice = function (product) {
    product.vat_price = product.price * 1.18;
}
```

Of course you have to replace this by your actual business logic for calculating the vat-price.

So the trick is to hand over the reference to the object of the product and update the value accordingly in place.

Comment: Please read carefully, `bought_product.vat_price` is inside a `ng-repeat`, that means that it's not accessible from controller just as you said...

Comment: oh you are right, i will correct my answer. please remove the down-vote if possible afterwards :)